# How can I fix the css for this element?

Tags: php, html, css

Hello there fellow stack exchange members hope your having a great day. Basically i picked up a project I never finished and started working on it. So far so good. Except until right now there's a CSS element that is giving me trouble.

Basically I have a menu bar with "Login" and "Register" if you inspect the code on Google chrome and select "menu" div the little highlight box shows up where it supposed to be but You cant see actually see it.

But in the "Matched CSS rules" if I uncheck "Float:right" and then check it again the  element goes to where its supposed to go, which is confusing me right now.

Could someone take a look at it for me. I'm currently developing on a throwaway domain before i actually transfer it to the real domain

Comment: you can check by reducing the margin top -ve value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like when you re-enable the float it's getting re-calculated in the DOM due to re-ordering. I think the root cause is that you have the div in the breadcrumb div instead of up a level in the homebar div.

Comment: Trying this solution now. THanks will get back to you.

Comment: Perfect! I can't believe i missed that. Thank you so much. Saved me a headache tonight.